# Prove the following trig identities

Tags: trigonometry

I am stuck on 7, 9

steps please, thank you

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Replace in the two equalities $1$ by $\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta$.

Comment: To prove for example 7. replace in the LHS $1$ by $\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta$ and you find the RHS.

Answer (score 1):

For the first one: note that $2\sin^2\theta - 1 = \sin^2\theta + \sin^2\theta -1$.

Second is similar.

Answer (score 1):

Identity #$7$:
$$2\sin^2 \theta-1=\sin^2 \theta - \cos^2 \theta$$
Let's make the right hand side equal to the left hand side (LHS-RHS proof).
$$\sin^2 \theta - \cos^2 \theta$$
$$=1-\cos^2 \theta - \cos^2 \theta$$
$$=1-2\cos^2 \theta$$
$$=1-2(1-\sin^2 \theta)$$
$$=1-2+2\sin^2 \theta$$
$$=-1+2\sin^2 \theta$$
$$=2\sin^2 \theta-1$$
$$\displaystyle \boxed{\therefore 2\sin^2 \theta-1=\sin^2 \theta - \cos^2 \theta}$$
Identity #$9$:
$$\cos^2 t=\sin^2 t +2\cos^2 t - 1$$
This time, let's ASSUME the identity is true.
$$\cos^2 t=\sin^2 t +2\cos^2 t - 1$$
$$-\cos^2 t=\sin^2 t - 1$$
$$-\cos^2 t - \sin^2 t = -1$$
$$\cos^2 t + \sin^2 t = 1 \ \ \text{(This must be true)}$$
$$\displaystyle \boxed{\therefore \cos^2 t=\sin^2 t +2\cos^2 t - 1}$$
If you do not like my proof for the second one, here is a more... appropriate proof. Let's use LHS-RHS again.
$$\cos^2 t=\sin^2 t +2\cos^2 t - 1$$
Let's make the right hand side equal to the left hand side.
$$\sin^2 t +2\cos^2 t - 1$$
$$=\sin^2 t + \cos^2 t + \cos^2 t -1$$
$$=1 + \cos^2 t - 1$$
$$=\cos^2 t$$
$$\displaystyle \boxed{\therefore \cos^2 t=\sin^2 t +2\cos^2 t - 1}$$
I hope that this solves your problems.